# scala pattern matching on object type and method accepting argument of many types

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types, matching

I want to execute method which accepts some object as an argument. There can be many different objects I can pass. There objects have different types (instances of various classes) but they all have common methods (methodA, methodB). So, I have problem with defining Types and this is what I do at the moment as an example. Anybody can help to fix it?

```
sealed trait Foo
final case class A(a: SomeClass1Type) extends Foo
final case class B(b: SomeClass2Type) extends Foo


object SomeObject {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val caseMatcher = new SomeClass1
  //  val caseMatcher = new SomeClass2

  execute(caseMatcher)

  def execute(caseMatcher: Either[SomeClass1Type, SomeClass2Type]) = {
    caseMatcher match {
      case a: A(SomeClass1) => executeCase1(new SomeClass1)
      case b: B(SomeClass2) => executeCase2(new SomeClass2)
    }
  }

  def executeCase1(param: SomeClass1Type) {
    val a = param.methodA
    val b = param.methodB
  }

  def executeCase2(caseMatcher: SomeClass2Type) {
    val a = param.methodA
    val b = param.methodB
  }
}
```

Comment: `Either` is not a union type - you need to match left or right. Also, method overloading would be easier to implement here.

Comment: I know I can not use Either but I use Either here to show I can input eny of two types but I do not know know how to solve it so execute method could accept any of the two types and I do not know what type I should set to the caseMAtcher argument in the execute method to accept any of the two types and still being able to access methods on the object within the executeCase

Comment: @user I need to match Left[Type1, Type2] or Right[Type1, Type2] but what should be the type of caseMatcher in execute method because obviosuly my IDE will complain.

Comment: You want to implement [**Polymorphism**](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) hope the link helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need the [structural-types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#structural-types):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val c1 = SomeClass1(1)
    val c2 = SomeClass1(2)

    val result1 = process(c1) // 5
    val result2 = process(c2) // 8
  }

  def process[T <: {def multiply: Int; def sum: Int} ](t: T): Int = t.multiply + t.sum

  case class SomeClass1(int: Int) {
    def multiply: Int = int * 2
    def sum: Int = int + 2
  }

  case class SomeClass2(int: Int) {
    def multiply: Int = int * 3
    def sum: Int = int + 3
  }
```

But be aware it could make great performance degradation if will be used in the frequently called pieces of code.